# How do i copy to a List?

Tags: c++-cli

I have this code in CLI

```
List<Codec^> ^GetCodecs()
{
    List<Codec^> ^l = gcnew List<Codec^>;


    bool KeepLooping = Encoder_MoveToFirstCodec();
    while (KeepLooping)
    {
        Codec ^codec = gcnew Codec(); // here... and that call encoder_init many times... which call register codec many times... which is a mass...

        codec->Name = gcnew String(Encoder_GetCurrentCodecName());
        codec->Type = Encoder_GetCurrentCodecType();

        char pix_fmts[200]; // array of 200 is probably enough
        int actual_pix_fmts_sz  = Encoder_GetCurrentCodecPixFmts( pix_fmts , 200 );

        for (int i = 0 ; i < actual_pix_fmts_sz ; i++)
        {
            //copy from pix_fmts to the :List

            codec->SupportedPixelFormats->Add(pix_fmts[i]);

        }
```

This is the Encoder_GetCurrentCodecPixFmts function in C:

```
int Encoder_GetCurrentCodecPixFmts( char *outbuf , int buf_sz )
{
  int i=0;
    while ( (i<buf_sz) && (codec->pix_fmts[i]!=-1) )
    {
        outbuf[i] = codec->pix_fmts[i];
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

This is a new class i did:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

public ref class Codec
{
public:
    String^ Name;
    int ID; // this is the index
    int Type; // this is the type
    List<int> ^SupportedPixelFormats;


    Codec(void)
    {
        SupportedPixelFormats = gcnew List<int>;
        // do nothing in the constructor;
    }

};
```

Which contain also the: SupportedPixelFormats
The constructor in this new class should be empty but i needed somewhere to make an instance for the List make a NEW for the List.

Now in the C++ i need to transfer from pix_fmts char array to codec->Supported
Or to copy from pix_fmts to the :List

So i did as above:

```
codec->SupportedPixelFormats->Add(pix_fmts[i]);
```

But i'm not sure if this the meaning of copy.

Is that right what i did ?

Comment: @H2CO3 you know what happens when you mix acid with water :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, it's a kind of a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Methods_of_copying). What makes you think it doesn't work? Do the results turn out wrong? If they do, put a breakpoint in there and try to get what is wrong.

Instead of copying one by one perhaps you can use the `Enumerable::ToList` extension method.

I hope this helped you.